# Find pairs with small difference in value

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In a single table I need to find those pairs for which the values of a certain differ by maximum a given amount. For example, given the following table and the maximum difference `0.5`:

```
val
---
1
1.2
1.3
4
4.5
6
```

The desired result would be:

```
val1 | val2
-----+-----
1    | 1.2
1    | 1.3
1.2  | 1.3
4    | 4.5
```

The main problem is that my table is gigantic and a cross product is not possible in reasonable time. i.e. this does **not** work:

```
SELECT t1.val, t2.val
FROM table t1, table t2
WHERE abs(t1.val - t2.val) <= 0.5
```

Is there a way to do this? I read up upon [window functions](https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/sql-window-functions/), so at least I know it is possible to compute for each entry the difference in value to the previous entry, obtaining for the example above:

```
val | diff
----+-----
1   | 0
1.2 | 0.2
1.3 | 0.1
4   | 2.7
4.5 | 0.5
6   | 1.5
```

From here on I need to find the ranges where the sum of `diff` does not exceed the given maximum. Is this possible? Are there more reasonable approaches?

I'm using spark.

Thank you.

**EDIT**: As pointed out, my query would also include symmetric pairs as well es pairs where the values are equal. Sorry for the ambiguity.

However, this is not the point. My problem is the join. The dataset is too large for a cartesian product. I am looking for a solution which avoids using one.

Also, the size of the dataset I'm dealing with is 1000000 tuples. I am not
sure what execution time to expect, but it was suggested that there must be a solution which avoids using a cartesian product on the data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you tried is close. Just a few modifications needed:

```sql
select t1.val,t2.val
from tbl t1
join tbl t2 on t2.val-t1.val<=0.5 and t1.val<t2.val
```

Comment: This also performs a cross product on the data. it is not considerably faster than my solution. My main issue is speed.

Comment: To be fair my example query would not have produced the desired output on the example. I edited according to your answer. Still, it is too slow.

Comment: your solution produces symmetric pairs like `(1,1.2)` and `(1.2,1)` and also gives out the same numbers `(1,1)`. This solution avoids them.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Sorry for the bad edit. I hope this time i did better.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate virtual time-based window:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._  // Where spark is an instance of SparkSession

val df = Seq(1.0, 1.2, 1.3, 4.0, 4.5, 6).toDF("val")

val w = window(
  $"val".cast("timestamp"), "1000 milliseconds", "500 milliseconds"
).cast("struct<start:double,start:double>").alias("window")

val windowed = df.select(w, $"val")
```

join and filter and remove duplicates:

```
val result = windowed.alias("left")
  .join(windowed.alias("right"), "window")
  .where(abs($"left.val" - $"right.val") <= 0.5 && $"left.val" < $"right.val")
  .drop("window").distinct
```

Result:

```
result.show
// +---+---+
// |val|val|
// +---+---+
// |1.0|1.2|
// |1.2|1.3|
// |4.0|4.5|
// |1.0|1.3|
// +---+---+
```

Comment: How is this not using a cartesian product? I'm sorry, but I don't understand.

Comment: Please check execution plan. `join(windowed.alias("right"), "window")` creates equi-join component and compares only the rows covered by the window.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have been advised to do is adding a `bucket` column so that each possibly matching tuples must be either in the same bucket or in adjacent buckets. Thus I can join (equijoin) the table with itself based on buckets and extract tuples from the result where the condition does indeed hold. I'm not sure if it is a good solution and I have not yet been able to verify it.

```
/* max difference cannot span more than 2 buckets */
spark.sql("set max_diff=0.001")
var dec_count = 3
var bucket_size = scala.math.pow(10,-1 * dec_count)

var songs_buckets = songs.orderBy(col("artist_familiarity")).withColumn("bucket", round(col("artist_familiarity"), dec_count))

/*
tuples in adjacent buckets can have very close `artist_familiarity`.
add id to avoid duplicate pairs or tuples paired with themselves.
*/
songs_buckets = songs_buckets.withColumn("bucket2", $"bucket" - bucket_size).withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())

songs_buckets.createOrReplaceTempView("songs_buckets")

var tmp = sql("SELECT s1.title as t1, s2.title as t2, s1.artist_familiarity as f1, s2.artist_familiarity as f2, s1.id as id1, s2.id as id2 FROM songs_buckets s1 JOIN songs_buckets s2 ON s1.bucket = s2.bucket OR s1.bucket = s2.bucket2")

tmp.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")

var result = sql("SELECT t1, t2 FROM tmp WHERE id1 < id2 and f2 - f1 <= ${max_diff}")

result.show()
```

I haven't bothered to change variable names back to the example in the question. It displays the first 20 rows of the result after about 12 seconds. Not sure if this has something to do with lazy loading, because it won't display the `count` of the result, but it's the best thing I could make work.